# Django - form Clean() and field errors

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-validation

I'm trying to set field errors in a form clean() and I'm currently doing:

```
self._errors['address'] = self._errors.get('address', ErrorList())
self._errors['address'].append(_(u'Please specify an address.'))
```

Is there a better and if possible shorter method for doing this?

Comment: use self.errors instead, it returns _errors and is not meant to be private

Answer (score 14):

New in Django 1.7 is `Form.add_error( field, message )`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this will help you . Its generally preferred you override clean and inside the function you could do the following

If you want to raise form specific errors you could do .

```
self._errors["field"] = ErrorList([u"Error"])
```

this is make sure you get the error class

if you have an non field error you could simple raise a validation error like so

```
raise forms.ValidationError(_("Error"))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

1. Standard way is `raise ValidationError(message)`.
2. Move field-specific validation to `clean_<fieldname>()` methods, `clean_address` in your case.  `ValidationError` raised in such method will attach error message to specific field.  One raised from `clean()` will be attributed to model in general.

Comment: I'm currently using `clean()` for validating certain things related to multiple fields -- I'm quite new to Django and Python in general and I was wondering if there was better/shorter way for checking/creating/appending field specific errors.

Comment: Added item #3, perhaps it describes what you need.  Taken from django's internal implementation of `clean_fields`

Comment: Can you expand on your suggestion #3? It doesn't work for me. I can see that the [`ValidationError` class](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/exceptions.py#L41) accepts a dictionary of errors like that, but [`Forms._clean_form`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L297) doesn't actually make use of it.

Comment: @AlexLebedev - I haven't tested your third suggestion but according to the docs that would be incorrect, no? When setting field specific errors, one should assign messages to `self._errors`.

Comment: You're right, I confused form and model validation. #3 will only work for models.